# share volume among replication controller in kubernetes

Tags: volume, kubernetes

Scenario:
  I am deploying apache2 as an RC with 3 replicas. so three pods will be created based on the load. i need each pod to have its own log folder mounted with host-node without being shared. hostpath should be as /{podname-containername}/var/log/apache2/access.log for each pod in runtime while spanning a new replica(new pod).

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way of gathering logs in Kubernetes is using fluentd, and navigate them using Elasticsearch/Kibana.

Nodes are not as ephemeral as pods, but to some extent they can be considered ephemeral in a k8s cluster, so It's highly recommended that you don't drop your log files to volumes on the host node.

That said, the only solution I can think of for your scenario is creating a `hostPath` volume on everypod, creating a folder using an arbitrary name, and using that folder to store logs.

If you need to know which pod is writing the logs, you can prefix the folder name with the container/pod name.

Comment: yes, i am doing exactly the same thing. what i need know is, when the kube brings up a new replica(pod) in case of load balancing, the newly created replica(pod) should use a different hostPath, i.e, the replica(pod) should not share same hostPath. I planned to create hostPath with pod name, but hostPath should be specified with the RC YAML file while creating an RC. How can this be specified in run time?

Answer (score 1):

[The doc on the downward API](http://kubernetes.github.io/docs/user-guide/downward-api/) should help you